# Ajax Tab Control Selected Index Changes On Page Refresh in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using AjaxToolJit Tab Container and the problem is when i refreshes the page the default tab is set to 0 but i was in 4th tab when i refreshed the page.

```
AutoPostBack=true
```

help me for a while but when i used UpdatePanel in the same page causes the same problem again.

Comment: Could you clarify the mention of "when i refreshes the page". Do you refresh page with F5 button?

Comment: Ya, i do refresh with F5 or some time when i submit the page it goes to tab index 1, but i have not redirected the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep selected tab index across full post back or page refreshing with F5 button then you must save selected tab index in session on `SelectedIndexChanged` event and then use this saved  index value in `Page_Load` event handler

Comment: @kishorejangid, this is solely one avialable way if you want to persist selected tabs across full postbacks.